# CSS - How to make scrollable columns take 100% of viewport

Tags: css

I have a layout with a header and three columns. The columns need to span the whole height of the viewport and also should be scrollable when the content is larger then the screen.

Comment: pls insert code examples

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using a combination of CSS Grid and Flexbox:

```
<div style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
  <div
    style={{
      display: "grid",
      gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr 1fr",
      gridTemplateRows: "min-content 1fr",
      height: "100%",
      gap: "1rem",
      overflow: "hidden",
      padding: "1rem"
    }}
  >
    <div style={{ display: "flex", gridColumn: "1 / 4" }}>
      <div style={{ background: "green", flex: 1, padding: "2rem" }}>
        HEADER
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      style={{
        height: "100%",
        overflow: "scroll",
        background: "yellow"
      }}
    >
      <p>
        Large content
      </p>
    </div>
    <div style={{ background: "red", flex: 1, padding: "2rem" }}>Col 2</div>
    <div style={{ background: "purple", flex: 1, padding: "2rem" }}>
      Col 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Edit wizardly-lumiere-y2hdu]

Answer (score 0):

Use `height: 100vh` on your columns. This will enlarge them to the point where they cover 100% of the **viewport height (vh)**.

By using this, your content won't be scrollable. If you want the columns to expand beyond the viewport height, use `min-height` instead of `height`, and add `overflow-y: scroll` to the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height: 100vh` on your columns style. It will set your div height to the height of your browser screen height. But if the content is larger than viewport it will expand. Therefore In the parent widget, you can put
overflow-y: scroll. to manage overflowed content as a scroll view.

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; display: flex; flex-direction:column">
  <div style="min-height:100vh;">
    <!-- Put content here -->
  </div>
<div>
```